# How to change code of every nth iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, erb

I got the following code in an .erb document:

```
<% @blog.order("created_at DESC").each do |d| %>

       <!-- Blog Card -->
       <div class="col-12 mb-3 mb-sm-7">
        <article class="row align-items-lg-center">
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <%= image_tag d.image.to_s, class:"img-fluid rounded" %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="py-5 px-lg-3">
              <span class="d-block mb-2">
                <p class="small text-body font-weight-bold text-cap"><%= d.tag_list %></p>
              </span>
              <h2>
                <%= link_to d.title, d, class:"text-inherit" %>
              </h2>
              <p><%= d.summary.truncate(100) %></p>
              <%= link_to "read more", d %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <!-- End Blog Card -->

<% end %>
```

I want the code to change every nth time so i have multiple "layouts" (not in the ruby sense) in my blog. for this i added an `if clause` with following code:

`<% if d.id % 5 == 0 %>`

Unfortunately that does not work very well since i want to weave in the layout alternative into the regular layout like this:

```
┌─────────┐
└─────────┘
┌──┐┌──┐┌─┐
└──┘└──┘└─┘
┌─────────┐
└─────────┘
┌──┐┌──┐┌─┐
└──┘└──┘└─┘
```

So one large article, next row with three small ones etc.

**Edit:**
The alternating layout looks like this:

```
      <div class="order-lg-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3 mb-sm-7">
        <!-- Blog -->
        <article
          class="card align-items-start flex-wrap flex-row h-380rem gradient-y-overlay-sm-dark bg-img-hero rounded-pseudo transition-3d-hover"
          style="background-image: url('<%= d.image.to_s %>');">
          <div class="card-header border-0 bg-transparent w-100">
            <p class="small text-white font-weight-bold text-cap mr-2"><%= d.tag_list %></p>
          </div>

          <div class="card-footer border-0 bg-transparent mt-auto">
            <%= link_to d do %>
            <h3 class="text-white"><%= d.title %></h3>
            <span class="text-white-70">Read more<i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-sm ml-1"></i></span>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </article>
        <!-- End Blog -->
      </div>
```

How do i implement such a layout?

**SOLUTION**

I managed to do what i wanted with a combination of `.each_with_index` and using partials. like this:

```
<% @blog.order("created_at DESC").each_with_index do |d, index| %>

<%= index % 4 == 0 ? render("blog/var1", d: d) : render("blog/var2", d: d) %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: so it is every other row has 3 in it, right?

Comment: @RockwellRice yes, every other row should contain article elements with `col-4` as class..

Comment: I would use `each_with_index` and then you can just do every even row as the three blocks.  So change `.each` to `.each_with_index` and then you can get the index in the loop, so change `|d|` to `|d, idx|` and then you can just use the modulo operator to test for even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```rb
<% @blog.order("created_at DESC").each_with_index do |d, index| %>

       <!-- Blog Card -->
       <div class="col-#{index % 4 == 0 ? '12' : '4'} mb-3 mb-sm-7">
        <article class="row align-items-lg-center">
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <%= image_tag d.image.to_s, class:"img-fluid rounded" %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="py-5 px-lg-3">
              <span class="d-block mb-2">
                <p class="small text-body font-weight-bold text-cap"><%= d.tag_list %></p>
              </span>
              <h2>
                <%= link_to d.title, d, class:"text-inherit" %>
              </h2>
              <p><%= d.summary.truncate(100) %></p>
              <%= link_to "read more", d %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <!-- End Blog Card -->

<% end %>
```

It means, for every 0, 4, 8, 12 .... index it'll add class `col-12`, otherwise it'll add class `col-4`

**EDIT:**

Yes, it is possible to insert whole partials as code:

Lets say, you created two separate files for small cards and big cards.
`_small_blog_card.html.erb` and `_big_blog_card.html.erb`

```rb
<% @blog.order("created_at DESC").each_with_index do |d, index| %>

  <% if index % 4 == 0 %>
    <%= render partial: 'big_blog_card', locals: {pass your data} %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: 'small_blog_card', locals: {pass your data} %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you! that indeed does work but unfortunately (i forgot to mention that) there are more changes than just the one column css class. is it possible to insert whole partials as code instead of just "12" and "4" ?

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder I updated my answer with your query. Please check.